# how to remove the default White border of dropdown of spinner

Tags: android, spinner

and used as:

```
citySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cityspinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cityadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.beijing_city, R.layout.spinner_item);
    cityadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_down_item);

citySpinner.setAdapter(cityadapter);

 my spinner_down_item.xml is:
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:background="@drawable/spinner_textview_rounded_corners"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:textColor="#ffff0000"
android:gravity="center"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

but the dropDownView as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2dcA.jpg
you can see there is a default  White rectangle border On the outermost layer,my question is how to remove it and not show scrollbar.thank you

Comment: Have you got any solution about the problem? I am now facing the same problem but haven't find any solution yet. Will appreciate that if you can tell me a way how to overcome the problem.